# How can another Python thread wait until a lock is released?

Tags: python, locking, python-multithreading

Given this code, how can I make sure that `get_model()` can always be called without waiting, unless `reload_lock` is active?

Preferably, I don't want `get_model()` to aquire the `reload_lock` itself, as all threads may freely call this method unless the application is reloading it's models.

```py
import threading

reload_lock = threading.Lock()


def get_model(name):
    # Normally this can be called, unless reload_models() is active
    # e.g. "if reload_lock.locked() -> wait until lock is released.
    ...


def reload_models():
    try:
        reload_lock.acquire()
        ...  # reload models
    finally:
        reload_lock.release()
```

Comment: and is reload_lock.locked() not working for you? That is how you check if a lock is locked. It returns True if the lock is acquired. False otherwise. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try like this, in the `get_model()`:

```
if reload_lock.locked():
    reload_lock.acquire()
    reload_lock.release()
```

I know it's an `acquire`, but can be a solution if you instantly `release` it.

Comment: I started with this, but in the end used a `readerwriterlock` package: https://github.com/elarivie/pyReaderWriterLock

Answer (score 1):

I was using thread locks for asynchronous user input on many functions and wanted something a bit more re-usable where the user input wouldn't be missed because the lock happened to be locked at that instance. So I bundled up checking the locks into a wrapper with a bit of a wait loop attached;

```
import threading
from functool import wraps
from time import sleep

lock = threading.Lock()

def wait_lock(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while lock.locked():
            sleep(0.001)
        lock.acquire()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        lock.release()
    return wrapper
```

You could also add a timeout on the while loop in case you accidentally threadlock yourself.